# Как настроить 404?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Дело в том что на хосте лежат куча сайтов и для всех единый htaccess в котором лежит путь к каждому из сайтов, так вот нужно для определенно назовем его example.com сделать так что если он выдает 404 открывалась 404.php

Comment: Добавить в .htaccess: код
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Comment: Так нужно что бы для конкретного сайта